# Using Pandas to insert a column on an existing large CSV file without consuming so much RAM

Tags: python, database, pandas, format, filesize

I am reading in a large CSV file using Python Pandas that is a little over 2GB in size. Ultimately, what I am attempting to do is add a "Date" column to the first index of the file, transpose the file from 364 rows and approximately 360,000 columns to only three columns ("Date", "Location", and "Data) with many, many rows instead. This will then be written out to a newly transposed CSV file.

For a little more context, each of the 364 rows represents each day of the year. For each day (and each row), there are thousands and thousands of site locations (these are the columns), each containing a measurement taken at the location.

The file looks like this right now:

```
Index     Location #1    Location #2    Location #359000...

0         Measurement    Measurement    Measurement
1         Measurement    Measurement    Measurement
2         Measurement    Measurement    Measurement
3         Measurement    Measurement    Measurement
364...    Measurement    Measurement    Measurement
```

I have attempted to add the new column by creating a date column using the Pandas "date_range" function and then inserting that column into a new dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

#read in csv file
df = pd.read_csv('Path to file')

#define 'Date' column
date_col = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2001', periods=364, freq='D')

#add 'Date' column at the 0th index to be the first column
df1 = df.insert(0, 'Date', date_col)

#rearrange rows to columns and index by date
long_df = df.set_index('Date').unstack().to_frame('Data').swaplevel().sort_index

#write out to new csv file, specifying two other columns via index label
long_df.to_csv('Transposed_csv_file', index=True, index_label=['Location', 'Data'])
```

The output I am looking for is a transposed CSV file that looks like this:

```
Date        Location          Data

1/1/2001    Location No. 1    Measurement 1
1/1/2001    Location No. 2    Measurement 2
1/1/2001    Location No. 3    Measurement 3
```

Once January 1st is complete, it will move on to January 2nd, like so:

```
1/2/2001    Location No. 1    Measurement 1
1/2/2001    Location No. 2    Measurement 2
1/2/2001    Location No. 3    Measurement 3
```

This pattern will repeat all the way to the end at 12/31/2001.

Three columns -- many rows. Basically, I am transposing from an X position to a Y position formatted CSV file.

What's happening right now is that when I attempted to run these lines of code, I noticed via the task manager that my memory was slowly being consumed, reaching beyond 96%. I have 32GB of RAM. There is no way a 2GB CSV file being read in by Pandas and outputting another large transposed file should consume that much memory. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or if there is a better method I can use to achieve the results I want. Thank you for your help.

Comment: With such a huge file I think you are better off using perl to do the transposition. As a first step you can use awk to change the indexes into dates. It will take some research.
Another option I can think of if you still want to do it using Pandas is sharding over the number of columns. Basically only reading a number of columns at a time, transposing, then appending to the main dataframe. Just ideas..

Comment: @Gal Sivan, I appreciate the response, however, I am quite sure I can do this with Pandas, as I have transposed a smaller, but different type of csv file using similar code above. In the former case, the columns I needed were already there. I just had to reformat it. It does work. I just need to know how to add a date column at the 0th index and then I can reformat it accordingly.

Comment: then you can do the second method reading a few columns at a time. The thing with Pandas is that it's not always efficient with big data and in tasks like this will make a lot of copies of dataframes and leave them in memory. So if you process a small piece at a time and then add them together you might be able to pull it off

Comment: @Gal Sivan, does _chunksize_ do that? I know you can break up a file with many rows using that. Would I just read in a specified number of columns, process them, and then concatenate at the end?

Comment: I believe you can specify a list of columns to pull with `usecols` parameter. See here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
It states that it can save on memory and processing time.
You can also read as an iterator and process chunks with `chunksize`.